# How to take a whole number and divide it into whole numbers based on percentages?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

I've got a bit of a general head scratcher as far as algorithms go. I'm using ruby but this could really be a general programming question. Here's the business requirements:

Lets say we have 5 sales reps, each of them with a certain percentage of backlogged work (work to be done). Lets say the backlog is $500,000 worth of work. Each sales rep has a certain percentage of that. Here's an arbitrary example:

- Sales Rep A: $53,230 (10.646% of the budget)
- Sales Rep B: $102,202 (20.4404% of the budget)
- Sales Rep C: $72,694 (14.5388% of the budget)
- Sales Rep D: $129,230 (25.846% of the budget)
- Sales Rep E: $142,644 (28.5292% of the budget)

Now lets say we want to divide a certain amount of workers available that these sales reps get allotted to do this work. For example, lets say that 50 workers are available to divy up based on these percentages.

How could I make sure that they are alloted evenly based on the percentages, but make sure to use only/all 50 workers? (If I just round the numbers, you could end up with 51 or 49)?

Comment: Round ⇒ do math ⇒ `[49,51].any? && add_or_subtract_to_min_or_max`.

Comment: There's no way around having some workers "left over" (consider the case when you have two sales reps, A 50% and B 50%, and three workers: you can't divide the three between the two.) You'll just have to decide what you do with the leftovers: assign them to a random rep, or the one who has the least, or the most, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Thats pretty simple in retrospect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the lower result, in this case 49, and then have a second routine that priorities how the remainder is distributed, e.g. by highest percentage or by best sales person, etc. Call the list the remainder distribution list.

Now since the remainder will always be less than the divisor starting with the top item in the remainder distribution list allocate one to the top of the list, then one to the next one on the list, etc. When you are out of units you are done. In your case you only have one unit to distribute so you only distribute one.

I ran into a similar problem with distributing packages from a warehouse. Works well with modulus arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

"...make sure that they are alloted evenly..." is vague. If viewed as an optimization problem we need a numeric measure of deviation that is to be minimized. For example, if one of the sales reps assigned `15` workers but deserved `14.3` based on percentage of sales, the deviation could be regarded to be `(15-14.3).abs #=> 0.7`. If we wished to minimize the maximum deviation over all sales reps, an optimal solution could be obtained using integer programming.

Something simpler is obviously needed. I would be inclined to allocate workers to reps in order of sales, lowest-to-highest, rounding off floats based on sales percentage.

**Code**

```
def allocate_workers(sales, workers)
  tot_sales = sales.values.sum.to_f
  sales.sort_by(&:last).each_with_object({}) do |(rep, amt),h|
    h[rep] = (workers * amt/tot_sales).round
    tot_sales -= amt
    workers -= h[rep]
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
sales = { A: 53_230, B: 102_202, C: 72_694, D: 129_230, E: 142_644 }
workers = 50

allocate_workers(sales, workers)
  #=> {:A=>5, :C=>7, :B=>10, :D=>13, :E=>15}
```

**Explanation**

For the example above the steps are as follows.

```
a = sales.values
  #=> [53230, 102202, 72694, 129230, 142644] 
b = a.sum
  #=> 500000 
tot_sales = b.to_f
  #=> 500000.0 
c = sales.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [[:A, 53230], [:C, 72694], [:B, 102202], [:D, 129230], [:E, 142644]] 
e = c.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[:A, 53230], [:C, 72694], [:B, 102202], [:D, 129230],
  #                  [:E, 142644]]:each_with_object({})>
```

The first element of the enumerator `e` is generated and passed to the block, assigning values to the block variables.

```
(rep, amt),h = e.next
  #=> [[:A, 53230], {}] 
rep
  #=> :A 
amt
  #=> 53230 
h
  #=> {} 
f = amt/tot_sales
  #=> 0.10646 
m = workers * f
  #=> 5.323 
h[rep] = m.round
  #=> 5 
tot_sales -= amt
  #=> 446770.0 
workers -= h[rep]
  #=> 45
```

So rep `:A` is assigned `5` workers (rounded from `5.323`), leaving 45 workers to be assigned to the remaining `4` reps, whose combined sales were `500000.0 - 53230 #=> 446770.0`.

The next element of the enumerator `e` is generated and passed to the block, resulting in the block variables having the following values.

```
(rep, amt),h = e.next
  #=> [[:C, 72694], {:A=>5}] 
rep
  #=> :C 
amt
  #=> 72694 
h
  #=> {:A=>5}
```

Note that `h` (which will be returned) has been updated. The remaining calculations follow those for the first element from `e` that was passed to the block.

When the rep with the largest sales (`:E`) is processed, the block variables will be

```
rep
  #=> :E 
amt
  #=> 142644  
h
  #=> {:A=>5, :C=>7, :B=>10, :D=>13}
```

and we will have

```
tot_sales
  #=> 142644.0 (approx.)
workers
  #=> 15
```

so rep `:E` will be given all

```
15 * 142644/142644.0).round
  #=> 15
```

remaining workers.